# PIR Sensor Interference When RF Transmitting

Tags: rf, battery-operated, attiny, interference, pir

I have created a small DIY circuit which sends a signal over 433.92Mhz when a PIR sensor is triggered.

The circuit consists of 4 modules soldered onto stripboard.

Schematic:

---

[image]

---

Components are:

- 0.71mm tinned copper bridging wire.
- HT7333-A regulator with 2x 10uf ceramic caps.
- TC4056 charger module with protection
- Original ATtiny212 @ 1Mhz 3.3V + 100uf cap across it
- 2x 22MΩ pullup resistors with 4.7nf debounce capacitors
- WL102-341 TX module 17.3cm LAN line antenna (switched on just before TX)
- MH-SR602 PIR Sensor (set to 2s close time. Also removed regulator on module to save current)
- 13400 3.7v 550mAh Li-ion vape battery (very good condition)

SMD resistors and capacitors are all 1206 and claimed to be original.

All modules except the TC4056 module are lifted off the board via female headers.

Everything works but I noticed 2 issues:

**Issue 1**

Soldering a 100uf ceramic (Samsung?) cap to the TX for added stability made the circuit start drawing about 1.7mA more current than the usual +-85µA.

It may be just a useless habit but I like to always solder an extra 100uf ceramic on the VCC and GND pins of these RF modules (E.G FS1000A, SYN1115 and WL102-341 TX modules)

Testing the capacitor twice showed 132.6uf and Vloss of 0.5%

Usually adding this extra capacitor does not increase current so is it correct to just assume faulty capacitor?

In this case I just de-soldered it and the current draw was fine again.

In the image PCB ENCLOSURE OPEN you can see the two 100uf caps on the MH-SR602 and WL102-341 modules. I only had to de-soldered the one on the WL102-341 module.

**Issue 2**

When the PIR triggers the module stays on longer then the 2s... this only happens in circuit. Testing the module separate works as normal. 2s interval.

Checking the PIR module in circuit with a multimeter in mA mode DC while TX shows it jumping around.

Now I was able to solve this in software by adding a 5s delay after TX but I would like to know what could be the cause?

I tried adding a simple resistor & capacitor RF filter.. no change. so I don't think it's noise.

During TX the whole circuit only draws around 12.5mA DC MAX so it's not like current or brownout (HT7333-A and li-ion battery should be more then sufficient)

I think that the transmitter might be too close to the RF module or maybe the 433.92 signal somehow interferes with the PIR sensor. Maybe there's some AC noise?

Maybe the regulator is to far from the PIR sensor?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

See images below.

---

PCB FRONT

[image]

---

PCB BACK

[image]

---

PCB ENCLOSURE OPEN

You can see filter circuit 1000uf but ultimately removed.

Also 2 100uf SMD caps only the one on TX module removed to solve current increase.

### [image]

PCB ENCLOSURE CLOSED

[image]